# Linux Mint 19.3 fresh install boot to busybox / initramfs

Tags: linux-mint, boot, initramfs, busybox

I made a fresh install of Mint 19.3 on my SSD (no other OS on the disk).

On boot, I have the Mint logo, then drop to `busybox` : [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmaXq.jpg). I have seen other poeple with similar problem, yet I didn't help (for example [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=272360)): from live USB, I could check my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=20c5990e-d7b4-46ca-b5e2-352285c2b9cd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=923c1022-a27d-4b82-9f6a-f3c9cede0db0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=bf7b61c0-7b27-4f6b-bcc2-7ff1abc7e384 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Results of `blkid` from the live session show

```
mint@mint:~$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="923c1022-a27d-4b82-9f6a-f3c9cede0db0" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="46b69021-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="20c5990e-d7b4-46ca-b5e2-352285c2b9cd" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="46b69021-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="bf7b61c0-7b27-4f6b-bcc2-7ff1abc7e384" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="46b69021-03"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Stockage" UUID="3D899484509A06C4" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="68648e36-cfde-4f24-a783-f3998b6214dc"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="b83e6a1b-ee9d-47f4-9738-23e5498126a5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9fff7545-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
```

So fstab has the correct UUID (for `sda1`, `sda2` and `sd3`, respectively `/`, `/boot` and `/home`), but according to the `busybox` message, when booting it tries to reach the UUID of `sdc1` which is my live boot key. How to correct that and boot on `sda1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution has been found with this install. I tried reinstalling using the same medium : same result.

Solution: create a new USB key of Mint 19.3, then reinstall from fresh

Possible reason for the bug: the USB key I used was using `multibootUSB`. Apparently it doesn't goes well with mint (though I worked well for Ubuntu and Kubuntu)